# When do I get my Settlement

Tags: settlement, mediation

On May 8 I had a mediation with defendant’s  attorney we agreed on a settlement. How long do they have before they must pay me the agreed amount. It’s been over 2 months.

Comment: There is not enough context to give you a useful answer. The amount, the language of the settlement, the type of settled claim(s) are some relevant factors in an assessment, especially if the deadline was not defined in the settlement. Actually you should have ensured that the settlement indicates a deadline.

Answer (score 2):

### What did you agree?

They must pay you by the time that you agreed in the settlement that they must pay you. If you didn't agree then they must pay within a reasonable time. 2 months might or might not be a reasonable time depending on the circumstances.

Note that a settlement agreement from a mediation is not binding like a court or arbitration award. It is itself a contract and if you want to enforce that contract you have to follow the dispute resolution process in the agreement or, if there aren't any, sue.